# How to delete the content of a txt file with vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make transactions with SAP, I use a csv file as an exported file, but in the end I would like to delete the content of this file without deleting the file itself. Just delete the content.

```
      Sub OpenCSVFile()
       '
       ' Load the CSV extract
       '

       '
     With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & fpath & "\" & ffilename, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "text"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

     End With


     With ActiveSheet
    .Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete 'delete first column
    .Rows("1:7").EntireRow.Delete 'delete first 7 rows
     End With

     End Sub
```

Comment: Just create a new text file in the same location and close without writing anything.  Far easier.

Answer (score 9):

```
Sub ClearContents()

    Open "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test1.csv" For Output As #1: Close #1
    MsgBox "Clear complete"

End Sub
```

Just change the file path to where your csv file is.

Comment: I don't want to delete it, I just want to delete the content so it's empty

Comment: @XDSSIOP This clears the contents of the csv file. It does not delete the csv file itself. It leaves you with a blank csv file is what you are asking for, is it not?

Comment: This is the best approach.